How to get all coursework due in the future with Google Classroom API?
I want to fetch all coursework currently due and insert it, formatted, into a Google Sheet. That means all coursework that has a due date in the future. I've never used the Google Classroom API. How would I do this in Apps Script? Thanks.

I believe the following should get you started with what you need.

In relation to your goal of fetching coursework with future due dates, take note that the Classroom API currently supports only three Classwork types: Assignments, Short answer questions, and Multiple-choice questions. For more details, you can refer to Google Classroom API documentation.

This is the Google Classroom API quickstart for Google Apps Script https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/apps-script

Fetch All Coursework that has Due Date
You may use this sample script as a basis for yours (which fetches all the courseworks with due dates on Google Classroom). Kindly follow the step by step procedure below.

Steps:
1.) On your spreadsheet, open Apps script via extensions.
2.) On the app script, click the + icon on Services and add Google Classroom API.
3.) Navigate to Project Settings and tick the box for Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor
4.) appsscript.json:
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Manila",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Classroom",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "classroom"
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}

Note: Set your preferred timezone
5.) Code.gs:
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cl = Classroom.Courses.list();
  var id = cl.courses.map(c => c.id);
  var cw = id.map(x => Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(x));
  var dt = cw.map(x => x.courseWork.map(y => y.dueDate).map(z => [z.year, z.month, z.day].toString()));
  var op = cw.map(x => x.courseWork.map(y => y.id)).flat().map((x, i) => [new Date(dt.flat()[i]), x]).filter(x => x[0] > new Date());
  var rg = ss.getRange(1, 1, op.length, op[0].length);
  rg.setValues(op);
}

6.) Expected output after Run:

7.) Sample Course Works created on Google Classroom:



Reference:
Manage Coursework and Grades
